# Plot horizontal lines on specific dates in Pinescript

Tags: pine-script

I am new to pinescript & programming. I want to plot horizontal lines at certain levels on 5-min charts everyday. These levels change everyday and will be manually defined by me.

Can someone help me with a code? On reading online I could understand basic functions like plot() and plotting basic lines, but unable to create a logic for lines to change everyday.

Eg: On 1st March, the levels to be drawn can be 16700 & 16800; On 2nd March, the levels to be drawn can be 16900 & 17000, so on & so forth.

Thanks in advance,
Karthik!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `vline()` function created by ImmortalFreedom.

```
//@version=4
study("vline() Function for Pine Script v4.0+", overlay=true)

vline(BarIndex, Color, LineStyle, LineWidth) => // Verticle Line Function, ≈50-54 lines maximum allowable per indicator
    // return = line.new(BarIndex,   0.0, BarIndex,     100.0, xloc.bar_index, extend.both, Color, LineStyle, LineWidth) // Suitable for study(overlay=false) and RSI, Stochastic, etc...
    // return = line.new(BarIndex,  -1.0, BarIndex,       1.0, xloc.bar_index, extend.both, Color, LineStyle, LineWidth) // Suitable for study(overlay=false) and +/-1.0 oscillators
    return = line.new(BarIndex, low - tr, BarIndex, high + tr, xloc.bar_index, extend.both, Color, LineStyle, LineWidth) // Suitable for study(overlay=true)

if(bar_index%10==0.0) // Generically plots a line every 10 bars
    vline(bar_index, #FF8000ff, line.style_solid, 1) // Variable assignment not required
```

Or you can use the `style = plot.style_columns` trick.

```
//@version=4
study("", "", true, scale = scale.none)
cond = close > open
plot(cond ? 10e20 : na, style = plot.style_columns, color = color.silver, transp=85)
```